# LCD on top of SD datalogger flickers help!

Tags: lcd, spi, button, sd, error

I have a problem with my 16,2 with buttons lcd shield.(LCD Keypad Shield). It is connected on top of an SD dataloger. I came to the conclusion that every time the sd shield logs data and completes the loop it switches off and on,flickering the lcd, and moves on with the loop. Is there any way to stop the flickering while the sd shield logs??[image: SD Loger][image: Side][image: Top]

Comment: Which LCD is that? I think the problem is that both boards use some of the same pins, creating a bit of conflict.

Comment: It says that it is a 1602 keypad lcd shield. I bought it from here: https://www.cableworks.gr/ilektronika/arduino-and-microcontrollers/displays/lcd/lcd-keypad-shield-with-16x2-for-arduino/

Comment: If it is [this one](https://majenko.co.uk/sites/default/files/pdf/lcd.pdf) then pin D10 is the backlight control. D10 is often used as a chip select pin, and is most likely the chip select for your SD card.  The only cure is physical modification of the LCD shield to remove pin 10 and connect it elsewhere (or leave it disconnected for always on by the looks of things).

Comment: I connected the lcd externally through a breadboard avoiding the d10 and it work like a charm!!! Thanks guys!

Comment: Some of these boards have solder-jumpers on the back, to change some of the pins. In your case, I'd snip the D10 header pin on the LCD shield. And then add a small wire from one of the free pins to (the now emasculated) D10 pin